# Java Connection pacakge with mysql not working for jsp pages in eclipse by usebean

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp

i made a package in eclipse to connect to mysql of wamp server to execute my sql query of a jsp page.This same code works perfectly fine on netbeans but not on eclipse.I think this is resulting as i was using glassfish server on netbeans and tomcat on eclipse.My package is located under src folder of java packages in eclipse.

This is my javabean object.

```
<jsp:useBean id="c1" scope="page" class="sql.connect" />
```

This is the error that i get unable to compile jsp class

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/IP Programming Discussion Platform] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page directive: invalid value for import
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.validateImport(Node.java:628)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.addImport(Node.java:609)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parsePageDirective(Parser.java:352)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1773)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:135)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:194)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Assuming "connect" is your class (uhm strange name, are you sure you aren't missing something after sql.connect?), have you tried with a simple import instead of direct bean import? <%@ page import="sql.connect">
<%connect c =new connect();...%>

Comment: i doesnt works.it works perfectly fine in netbeans but not in eclipse.